# Similar String Values in Rows in Dataframe

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have got a few rows in my data frame in R where the name of the disease is the same but the wording has changed slightly (the plus changed to a `>`).

Is there a way to quickly scan and merge such rows?

A few examples:

```
Row 59: 872 - SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV ***96+*** HOURS W/O MCC
Row 60: 872 - SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV ***>96*** HOURS W/O MCC

Row 3: 003 - ECMO OR TRACH W MV ***96+*** HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ 
Row 4: 003 - ECMO OR TRACH W MV ***>96 HRS*** OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `merge`. Do you just want to delete one of them?

Comment: I would suggest finding a common pattern and check this pattern several times to be sure that you won't lost valid data. 

Your example reveals the common pattern, the code at the beginning of each similar line (872 or 003). Remove all lines except the first occurrence which meets the pattern.

I would write a loop and append all rows to an array if they match the pattern and at the end remove all except the first occurrence.

Comment: @G5W I meant merging the values for those rows with a similar value

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many unique records you will have you can do text clustering:

```
> disease.df
     [,1]                                                            
row1 "SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV 96+ HOURS W/O MCC"          
row2 "SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV >96 HOURS W/O MCC"          
row3 "ECMO OR TRACH W MV 96+ HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ"
row4 "ECMO OR TRACH W MV >96 HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ"

> d <- adist(disease.df)
> rownames(d) <- disease.df
> hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
> data.frame(disease.df,cutree(hc,k=2))
                                                     disease.df 
cutree.hc..k...2.
row1           SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV 96+ HOURS W/O MCC                 
1
row2           SEPTICEMIA OR SEVERE SEPSIS W/O MV >96 HOURS W/O MCC                 
1
row3 ECMO OR TRACH W MV 96+ HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ                 
2
row4 ECMO OR TRACH W MV >96 HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ                 
2
```

Comment: I think for this answer to be useful, you would need to say what `hc` is.

Comment: Oh, thank you, some code did not copy in. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqdrg <- unique(drgs, incomparables = FALSE )
uniqdrg$drg <- substr(uniqdrg$drg, 0, 3)
uniqdrg <- uniqdrg %>% arrange(drg)
uniqdrg<-uniqdrg[uniqdrg$drg %in% uniqdrg$drg[duplicated(uniqdrg$drg)],]
```

I used this code to find the duplicate values.